# How to combine :first-child and :hover?

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list I'm using for a menu. Each item has a background image and a :hover image. The background image on the first element is different that the rest, so I use the following to style it, which works fine:

```
#prodNavBar ul:last-child li:first-child {...}
```

Since I want a roll-over image on this element as well, I've tried adding `:hover`, like so:

```
#prodNavBar ul:last-child li:first-child:hover {...}
```

...but this doesn't work. What's the syntax to combine `:first-child` and `:hover`?

Comment: For the love of Pete put a class or ID on that UL in prodNavBar -- a large amount of your userbase won't see this working properly a.k.a. the noobs a.k.a. the ones who click the ads a.k.a. the IE users

Comment: Yeah, since I have to put a class on the first element to get it to work in IE, I may as well just use the class name and forget this first-child business all together.

Comment: If it needs to work in IE6, you are indeed better off with plain old classes.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Chaining `:first-child` and `:hover` as you do here should work just fine. If you're using IE6, however, only the last pseudo-class in the chain will be recognized.

In other words, you're doing it right.

Comment: And how would you combine both them plus :not (all except the first-child)?

Comment: If I wanted all except the first child, I'd probably use something like `nth-child(n+2)`.

Answer (score 12):

`li:first-child:hover` should work. Which browser are you testing with? IE doesn't support `last-child`

[Here](http://jsbin.com/oyoce) is a sample test case.

Comment: `:last-child` only doesn't work in IE8 and lower. It works in IE9+ perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED [Similar Question Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53433146/css-last-child-and-hover-on-an-a-link-in-a-ul/53433241)

```
.aston-menu-light>ul>li:last-child > a:hover {
    color:red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following css code

```css
#prodNavBar ul:last-child li:nth-child(2n-1):hover
#prodNavBar ul:last-child li:nth-child(2n):hover
```

I use this in my project

```css
.buttons button:nth-child(2n) { background: white; border: 1px solid white; border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 0 0 3px tomato; transition: box-shadow .2s ease-in-out; }
.buttons button:nth-child(2n):hover { box-shadow: 0 0 10px tomato; }
.buttons button:nth-child(2n):active { box-shadow: 0 0 10px tomato; border: 1px solid tomato; }

.buttons button:nth-child(2n-1) { background: white; border: 1px solid white; border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 0 0 3px #39FF14; transition: box-shadow .2s ease-in-out; }
.buttons button:nth-child(2n-1):hover { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #39FF14; }
.buttons button:nth-child(2n-1):active { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #39FF14; border: 1px solid #39FF14; }
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
<button type="submit">submit</button>
<button type="reset">reset</button>
</div>
```