# CSS :last-child AND :hover on an a link in a ul

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover, href

I'm styling the last child of a navigation menu which I seem to be able to do fine with the following code:

```
.aston-menu-light ul > li:last-child {
    border:2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding:0 20px 0 20px;
} 

.aston-menu-light ul > li > ul > li:last-child {
    border:none !important;
    padding:0 !important;
} 

.aston-menu-light ul > li:last-child:hover {
    background-color:#ffff;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

The trouble comes when I try and target the `<a>` on the last child on hover. I'm using this:

```
.aston-menu-light ul > li > a:last-child:hover {
    color:red !important;
}
```

But it seems to style all of the `<a>` tags and not just the last child. I've tried variations such as: `ul > li a` but I can't seem to get it o work correctly.

I have a Codepen here: https://codepen.io/shaun-taylor/pen/LXdGGN

The main goal being for this one is just to turn the last link on the top level only red when you hover on it I guess - Thnk you for reading!

Comment: I'm guessing that all your a's are last children as they are probably the only child of the li, but as your question is off topic, I voted to close: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. (External links may rot and this is meant to be a repository of information for future users)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should change

```
.aston-menu-light ul > li > a:last-child:hover {
    color:red !important;
}
```

to

```
.aston-menu-light>ul>li:last-child > a:hover {
    color:red !important;
}
```

```css
/* CSS Document */


a {
 color: black;
}

nav {
 margin: 50px 0;

}

nav ul {
 padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 }
 
nav ul li {
 display:inline-block;
}

nav a {
 display:block;
 padding:0 10px; 
 color:#black;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height: 60px;
 text-decoration:none;
}


/* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
nav ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute; 
 top: 60px; /* the height of the main nav */
}
 
/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display:inherit;
}
 
/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
 width:170px;
 float:none;
 display:list-item;
 position: relative;
}

/* Second, Third and more Tiers */
nav ul ul ul li {
 position: relative;
 top:-60px; 
 left:170px;
}

 
/* Change this in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }

.aston-menu-light ul > li:last-child {
 border:2px solid blue;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding:0 20px 0 20px;
} 

.aston-menu-light ul > li > ul > li:last-child {
 border:none !important;
 padding:0 !important;
} 

.aston-menu-light ul > li:last-child:hover {
 background-color:#ffff;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
 -o-transition: all .5s;
 transition: all .5s;
} 

.aston-menu-light>ul>li:last-child > a:hover {
 color:red !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="aston-menu-light">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a>
          <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a>
          <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>        
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a>
          <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a>
          <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes, and for some extra information to Shaun, all the `<a>` elements are the "last-childs" of their `<li>` elements so all of them became red.

Comment: Thank you AboAlimk! Perfect - I understand what I did wrong now! Also, thank you Jeremy for the explanation :)

Answer (score 4):

Use This:

```
.aston-menu-light ul > li:last-child a:hover {
  color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shold rewrite

```
.aston-menu-light ul > li > a:last-child:hover {
  color:red !important;
}
```

to

```
.aston-menu-light ul > li:last-child > a:hover {
  color:red;
}
```

What you were doing wrong is that in all the `li` elements the `a` element is always the last child! Therefore in all of them, it will turn red when you hover.
What you needed was the last `li` element, therefore using `li:last-child`in the CSS.

Also, there is no need to use the `!important`, since this CSS selector is more specific than just

```
a {
  color: black;
}
```

It will be red anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this to simplify it.

```
.aston-menu-light ul li:last-child a:hover {
    color:red !important;
}
```